# How to create/disable intent-filter programmatically?

Tags: android, intentfilter

I have three activity and three Intent Filters for them in the Android Manifest.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>                 
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".firstActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:label="@string/first">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>  
   </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".secondActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:label="@string/second">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>  
   </activity>
   <activity 
        android:name=".thirdActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:label="@string/third">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>  
   </activity ></application>
```

How can I disable the intent filters programmatically depending on some options? Or how can I create new intent filters in code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 36):

You can neither enable, disable, or create `<intent-filter>`s programmatically.

However, in your case, you only have one `<intent-filter>` per component. In that case, you can enable and disable the *component* programmatically, via `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()`. In your case, enabling or disabling the activity would have the same basic effect as enabling or disabling its `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: What about  IntentFilter.create and Context.registerResolver ?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#create

Comment: @Koren: There is no `registerResolver()` method. You may be thinking of `registerReceiver()`. This is possible for `BroadcastReceivers`, but the OP is inquiring about activities. Also, `registerReceiver()` only works while your process is running, whereas an `<intent-filter>` works even when your process is not running.

Comment: Yes I was talking about registerReceiver sorry

Comment: I just tried to disable an activity via PackageManager, but the intent-filter stays alive. Any more suggestions?

Comment: @Grisgram: What you describe is not possible, at least by how I would define the terms that you used. You may wish to ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] and explain how you have determined that you both *successfully* disabled the activity *and* the `<intent-filter>` "stays alive".

Comment: It works - apologies - it was my own mistake and I commented a bit too fast here :) - sorry. It's all good. Works as described.

Comment: If you have more than one intent-filter per activity you could use activity-alias to disable them individually. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10403074/1954655

Answer (score 11):

If your Activity had multiple `intent-filter`s then you could disable a specific `intent-filter` by creating an `activity-alias` with the `intent-filter` you want to disable and disable just the Activity alias. See: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-alias-element.html

Answer (score 7):

> An intent filter is an instance of the IntentFilter class. However,
>   since the Android system must know about the capabilities of a
>   component before it can launch that component, intent filters are
>   generally not set up in Java code, but in the application's manifest
>   file (AndroidManifest.xml) as  elements. (**The one
>   exception** would be filters for broadcast receivers that are registered
>   dynamically by calling Context.registerReceiver(); they are directly
>   created as IntentFilter objects.)

source: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Also, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10403074/832776

Answer (score 1):

What I did is **registerReciever** and

```
registerReceiver(this.broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
```

and **unregister** the broadcastReciever

```
if (this.broadcastReceiver != null) {
        unregisterReceiver(this.broadcastReceiver);
    }
```